# karma test cases are running multiple times: Angular unit test

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, package.json, angular-unit-test

I am not able to understand why my karma test cases re runs multiple times after a fixed test case.

Disconnected, because no message in 50000 ms.
Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 131 of 251 DISCONNECTED (1 min 9.028 secs / 18.285 secs)

Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 131 of 251 DISCONNECTED (47.273 secs / 18.169 secs)

Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 131 of 251 DISCONNECTED (1 min 9.028 secs / 18.285 secs)

Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 131 of 251 DISCONNECTED (47.273 secs / 18.169 secs)

Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 97 of 251 DISCONNECTED (22.07 secs / 19.87 secs)

Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 131 of 251 DISCONNECTED (1 min 9.028 secs / 18.285 secs)

Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 131 of 251 SUCCESS (0 secs / 17.406 secs)

Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 239 of 251 SUCCESS (0 secs / 20.912 secs)

Below is the configuration of karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

const { join } = require('path');
const { constants } = require('karma');

module.exports = () => {
  return {
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: join(__dirname, '../../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: constants.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true,
  };
};
```

when I change singleRun to false and execute test case using ng test, it works fine, the problem is only when I change it to true.

I saw couple of blogs and tried to resolve it by adding some more configuration like

```
       browserNoActivityTimeout: 50000,
        captureTimeout: 60 * 1000,
        // captureTimeout: 210000,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 1,
        // browserDisconnectTimeout: 210000,
        // browserNoActivityTimeout: 210000
```

but nothing has worked for me.

Below is the configuration in devDependencies (I am using angular cli version 8)

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.800.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "0.800.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "6.0.1",
    "@nrwl/schematics": "~8.0.0",
    "@ruf/schematics": "next",
    "@ruf/wrench": "next",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^8.10.10",
    "codelyzer": "5.1.0",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "0.3.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.4",
    "prettier": "1.16.4",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "scss-bundle": "^2.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.4",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4"
  }
```

Please suggest !!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the above issue by spying on functions which has `location.href` set inside it.

`location.href` was causing the page to load with different URL and because of that karma was running again and again.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was exactly the problem I encountered too.

Comment: same thing but for `window.open`